# I made a button with ionic2. but it doesn't work at all. I added the codes

Tags: facebook, angular, button, ionic2

I made a button related to login with facebook.

when I click the button, it doesn't work at all.

I added the codes.

[image]
[image]

what should I do?
[image]

please, help me!

Comment: is this what you expect? https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/facebook-native.html

Comment: thank you so much. because of your help, my team-project must be very successful!!

Comment: I have a Git repo where I have implemented above cloud-based plugin.If you need it please let me know.I can share it with you.

Comment: sorry, could you tell me some comments about my code? frankly speaking, I can't find the hint to solve this problem. and can I take your git repo? thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done that and it's working fine on the real device.If you have any question, please comment below.

**Play with** [**Git Repo**](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/CloudFacebookLogin).

[**Cloud Plugin for more info**](https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/facebook-native.html).

**Note:** Fork above git repo and play with it.

***app.module.ts***

```
import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'd32c02d2'
  },
  'auth': {
    'facebook': {
      'scope': ['public_profile', 'email']
    }
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ],
  imports: [
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
   ],
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***home.html***

```
<button ion-button block type="button" (click)="fbLogin()">Fb Login</button>
```

***home.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FacebookAuth, User } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public facebookAuth: FacebookAuth, public user: User) {

  }

  fbLogin() {
    this.facebookAuth.login();
  }

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I think I can do solve this problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)